# How to make arithmetic operations depending on some conditions in google spreadsheet/excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet, lookup

I am new to google spreadsheet/excel and I need a job to be done. Please help me to solve this

| Dropdown | Price | Available amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 25 | 350 |
| User 2 | 30 | 500 |
| User 1 | 50 | ??? |
| User 2 | 75 | ??? |

What I want is when a user selects a user from the dropdown(first column) and fills in the price column, the 3rd column needs to auto-update with the value of the previous same user, available amount - Price of current row value.

i.e. in the given example, the 3rd row's last column value is filled with value 300 (350-50), and the 4th row's last column value is filled with value 425 (500-75). I have given the spreadsheet link for reference.

Ref: [**Spreadsheet example**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1foa7GIWBd7izYSEV3GrYr30R9wwf4aCVj47JHsvYNYc/edit#gid=0)

Comment: In Excel you could look into XLOOKUP which can look up instead of down. But I don't believe google has that.

Comment: `=XLOOKUP(A3,A1:INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1),C1:INDEX(C:C,ROW()-1),0,0,-1)-B3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this formula**

```
=IF(A4="",,INDEX(FILTER(C$2:C3, A$2:A3=A4), 
                 COUNTA(FILTER(C$2:C3, A$2:A3=A4)), 1)-B4)
```

[image]

Comment: HI, Thanks for your time. But I don't want an extra column as output. I want the updated value in **Available amount** itself. i.e. when we enter a value for price the **Available amount** should update itself. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: the answer is updated take a kook

Comment: Sorry for disturbing again. The latest one is not getting the latest **Available amount** value. It is fetching the value from first row.  I have updated it in the google sheet. Please refer to the link. Thanks again.

Comment: @BenkI You should be getting the right results if you use the latest formula.

Comment: @BenkI the answer is updated take a look.